# Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":21". - Trying to run headless Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, xvfb

I'm trying to run some Webdriver Maven tests on a headless server via xvfb using Chrome (Firefox also didn't work) but I'm getting this error message:

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":21".
```

What more information should I provide and what could the problem/solution be?

Comment: @kowalski I am facing similar issue, and none of the solution suggested here works for me, were you able to run chromedriver on remote box ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
Xvfb :21 -screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension RANDR &
```

```
Xvfb --help

+extension name        Enable extension
-extension name        Disable extension
```

Comment: Whats with the + or - used? What's the difference?

Comment: From the usage:  `+extension name        Enable extension
-extension name        Disable extension`

Answer (score 5):

Jeue's answer didn't help me. After hours I finally found the solution for my system and I think this will help other people too. I had to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH like this:

```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

After that, everything worked very well, even without any "-extension RANDR" switch.

Comment: Wow! great saved me after two days of debugging

Comment: Seems not needed on my system, because it is already written in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf which is loaded from /etc/ld.so.conf

Answer (score 2):

It seems that when this error appears it is an indication that the selenium-java plugin for maven is out-of-date.

Changing the version in the pom.xml should fix the problem

Comment: it was never obvious to me, thanks alot :) , I installed the latest jar and everything seems to be working perfectly now !!