# Firefox-38 is not working in headless mode on Amazon Linux-2015.03

Tags: firefox, amazon-linux, firefox-headless

I am trying to run firefox-38 on Amazon linux-2015.03 release in headless mode with salenium. But its giving me below error:

```
(process:4919): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: no display specified
```

I can not update my OS, because of some dependencies issue with our application. Also I have tried to use firefox-39. Its giving me the same issues. I am installing firefox by compiling it from source and all the required dependencies are installed.

Comment: You need a display to run Firefox. Xvfb (http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) will do the trick.

Comment: I exported the display but still the same error.

{ (process:7937): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99". }

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944234/xlib-extension-randr-missing-on-display-21-trying-to-run-headless-googl

Comment: Not really, issue there is about google chrome and  I am facing it on firefox-38. Also solution mentioned there is  not working for me. I am still facing that issue.

Comment: The odds on it being different based on the browser being used are slim. Good luck with resolving.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install firefox installation by copying glib2 and its dependency packages from CentOS-base repo to amazon linux instance. Installed them, which fixed the firefox installation issue.